# A query shows a value in mysql but it is displayed as null in HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The following query contain an encrypted patient name field:

```
SELECT 
    patient.patient_id as patient_id2,

    CONVERT(aes_decrypt(patient_name_en, :encKey) using utf8mb4) as patient_name_en2,

    visit.visit_id as visit_id,

    visit.date_of_visit as date_of_visit,

    medication.med_name as med_name,

    consultation_med.medication_collector as medication_collector,

    consultation_med.given_quantity as given_quantity,

    (SELECT 
        sum(consultation_med.given_quantity)

    FROM 

        med_pharmacy

    LEFT JOIN 

        medication

    ON

        med_pharmacy.med_id=medication.med_id

    LEFT JOIN 

        consultation_med

    ON 

    consultation_med.med_pharmacy_id=med_pharmacy.med_pharmacy_id

    LEFT JOIN

    consultation 

    ON 

        consultation.consultation_id=consultation_med.consultation_id

    LEFT JOIN

        visit
    ON
        visit.visit_id = consultation.visit_id

    LEFT JOIN

        patient
    ON 

        patient.patient_id = visit.patient_id

    WHERE med_pharmacy.med_id=:mid) as sumGiven

FROM 

    med_pharmacy

LEFT JOIN 

    medication

ON 

    med_pharmacy.med_id=medication.med_id

LEFT JOIN 

    consultation_med

ON 

    consultation_med.med_pharmacy_id=med_pharmacy.med_pharmacy_id
LEFT JOIN
    consultation 
ON 
    consultation.consultation_id=consultation_med.consultation_id
LEFT JOIN
    visit
ON
    visit.visit_id = consultation.visit_id
LEFT JOIN 
    patient
ON 
    patient.patient_id = visit.patient_id
WHERE 
    med_pharmacy.med_id=:mid
    and
    med_pharmacy.clinic_id=:cid
    and
    visit.visit_status = :visitStatus

ORDER BY
    visit.date_of_visit DESC
```

When running this query in MySQL, I cansee the name of the patient. But when I send the data as JSON array from PHP script to Ajax, the patient name is displayed as null in the network tab returned array and on screen.

Here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
require_once('connection.php');
header('Content-type: application/json');
$cid = $_SESSION['clinic_id'];
$mid = $_POST['mid'];
$encKey = ...//
$res_distribution = array();

$getMedicationsDist = "SELECT 
    patient.patient_id as patient_id2,
    CONVERT(aes_decrypt(patient_name_en, :encKey) using utf8mb4) as patient_name_en2,
    visit.visit_id as visit_id,
    visit.date_of_visit as date_of_visit,
    medication.med_name as med_name,
    consultation_med.medication_collector as medication_collector,
    consultation_med.given_quantity as given_quantity,
    (SELECT 
        sum(consultation_med.given_quantity)
    FROM 
        med_pharmacy
    LEFT JOIN 
        medication
    ON
        med_pharmacy.med_id=medication.med_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        consultation_med
    ON 
    consultation_med.med_pharmacy_id=med_pharmacy.med_pharmacy_id
    LEFT JOIN
    consultation 
    ON 
    consultation.consultation_id=consultation_med.consultation_id
    LEFT JOIN
    visit
    ON
    visit.visit_id = consultation.visit_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    patient
    ON 
    patient.patient_id = visit.patient_id
    WHERE med_pharmacy.med_id=:mid) as sumGiven
FROM 
    med_pharmacy
LEFT JOIN 
    medication
ON 
    med_pharmacy.med_id=medication.med_id
LEFT JOIN 
    consultation_med
ON 
    consultation_med.med_pharmacy_id=med_pharmacy.med_pharmacy_id
LEFT JOIN
    consultation 
ON 
    consultation.consultation_id=consultation_med.consultation_id
LEFT JOIN
    visit
ON
    visit.visit_id = consultation.visit_id
LEFT JOIN 
    patient
ON 
    patient.patient_id = visit.patient_id
WHERE 
    med_pharmacy.med_id=:mid
    and
    med_pharmacy.clinic_id=:cid
    and
    visit.visit_status = :visitStatus

ORDER BY
    visit.date_of_visit DESC";
$execGetMedicationsDist = $conn->prepare($getMedicationsDist);
$execGetMedicationsDist->bindValue(":visitStatus", "Active");
$execGetMedicationsDist->bindValue(":encKey", $mid);
$execGetMedicationsDist->bindValue(":mid", $mid);
$execGetMedicationsDist->bindValue(":cid", $cid);
$execGetMedicationsDist->execute();
//$getExecGetMedications = $execGetMedications->fetchAll();
$i=0;
foreach($execGetMedicationsDist as $var2)
{
    $res_distribution[$i]=$var2;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($res_distribution);

?>
```

And the AJAX call:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '../php/getMedicationDistributionReport.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {mid: searchTxt},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success:function(resp2)
                {
                    //append data

                    $("#med_table_distribution tr").fadeOut(400);
                    $("#med_table_distribution #after_tr_distribution").before("<tr class='bg-info'><th colspan='10' style='text-align: center'>Patient who received this medication =</th></tr><tr><th>Patient ID</th><th colspan='3'>Patient Name</th><th>Visit ID</th><th>Date of Visit</th><th colspan='2'>Medication Name</th><th>Collector</th><th>Quantity Given</th></tr>");
                    $.each( resp2, function(key, result2)
                    {
                        //var pid = result['patient_id'];
                        var sumGiven = parseInt(result2['sumGiven']);
                        //var profileBtn = "<a id='profileBtn'><span class='badge badge badge-info' style='background-color: #0090ff'>Patient Profile</span></a>"
                        $("#after_tr_distribution").after("<tr id="+result2['patient_id']+"><td>"+result2['patient_id2']+"</td><td colspan='3'>"+result2['patient_name_en2']+"</td><td>"+result2['visit_id']+"</td><td>"+result2['date_of_visit']+"</td><td colspan='2'>"
                            +result2['med_name']+"</td><td>"+result2['medication_collector']+"</td><td>"
                            +result2['given_quantity']+"</td></tr>");
                    });

                    //console.log(sumGiven);
                },
                error:function(resp2)
                {
                    console.log(resp2);
                }

            })
```

Comment: (How) have you verified that you are running the exact same query in both cases?

Comment: make sure print_r($res_distribution) before echo $res_distribution

Comment: Guys, just added `1` in all variables binded in PHP and on MySQL

Comment: It looks like you are missing some like off fetch method in your PHP code. Also show the file `connection.php`

Answer (score 0):

Your error lays in

```
foreach($execGetMedicationsDist as $var2)
{
    $res_distribution[$i]=$var2;
    $i++;
}
```

where it should be as

```
while($var2 = $execGetMedicationsDist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $res_distribution[]=$var2;
}
```

because `$execGetMedicationsDist` is a [PDOStatement object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) I have also removed `$i++` as you weren't using it anymore and not required. More info on [PDO::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: can you also run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';` from **php** and dump the results?

Comment: 'collation_database', 'utf8mb4_general_ci'

Comment: there should be at least 3 rows. `collation_connection` and `collation_server `

Comment: collation_connection utf8_general_ci

Comment: collation_server latin1_swedish_ci